# PHP foreach() last value not being compared

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of values as such:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [product_colour_sizes_id] => 37105
        [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 810
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 61
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 904
        [quantity] => 999
        [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes] => 16-165
        [product_colour_sizes_name_colours] => Red
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [product_colour_sizes_id] => 37104
        [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 810
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 61
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 905
        [quantity] => 999
        [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes] => 17-175
        [product_colour_sizes_name_colours] => Red
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [product_colour_sizes_id] => 37103
        [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 810
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 61
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 906
        [quantity] => 999
        [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes] => 185-19
        [product_colour_sizes_name_colours] => Red
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [product_colour_sizes_id] => 37102
        [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 810
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 61
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 907
        [quantity] => 999
        [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes] => 19.5  
        [product_colour_sizes_name_colours] => Red
    )

)
```

I then have a foreach loop which iterates over the above data and reduces each array down to a single row corresponding to different `[product_colour_sizes_name_sizes]`. However i have a problem that the last array is not being compared. Here is my loop:

```
foreach($product_combinations as $key => $product_combination){

if($key > -1){
    if($product_combinations[$key+1]['product_colour_sizes_name_colours']
        == $product_combinations[$key]['product_colour_sizes_name_colours']
      ){

        $color  = $product_combinations[$key]['product_colour_sizes_name_colours'];
        $color['name'] = $color;
        $id = $product_combinations[$key]['product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id'];
        $sizes[$id] = $product_combinations[$key]['product_colour_sizes_name_sizes'];
        $quantity = $product_combinations[$key]['quantity'];
        $sizes['quantity'] = $quantity;



        /* Dont forget theses*/
        $sizes['product_colour_sizes_id'] = $product_combination['product_colour_sizes_id'];
        $sizes['product_colour_sizes_product_id'] = $product_combination['product_colour_sizes_product_id'];
        $sizes['product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id'] = $product_combination['product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id'];
        $sizes["product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id$x"] =$product_combination['product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id'];
        $x++;
    } else {
        array_push($colours, 
        array(
            $color => $sizes

        ));

        unset($sizes);
        $x = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Essentially now, my 4th (`[3]`) array is being compared as 
`$product_combinations[$key+1] == $product_combinations[$key]['product_colour_sizes_name_colours']` with `$key+1` being an empty value.

I know the issue as stated above, but can't think of a good way to overcome it with my current logic, can anyone think of a solution?

**Edit**
What i am attempting to do is reduce the row down to this exact array structure (with the last array included of course that is currently not be added):

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Red] => Array
            (
                [904] => 16-165
                [quantity] => 999
                [product_colour_sizes_id] => 37103
                [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 810
                [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 61
                [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id0] => 904
                [905] => 17-175
                [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id1] => 905
                [906] => 185-19
                [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id2] => 906
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to hard code `$key + 1` type keys anywhere, using multi-dimensional arrays should be a good alternative. If you can't get around it, make sure you check that the array key exists before trying to access it..

Comment: It may empty because its characters and not numbers. Try it like this -- [product_colour_sizes_name_colours] => "Red"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit unclear on your original core logic, but based on your example output data, I believe the solution below should work.

The key is really understanding your final desired output because a lot of the logical loops the original code goes through can be eliminated by just using the magic of associative arrays. This solves the whole `$key+1` matching `$key` issue—which would never get the last value due to the inherent flaw in `$key+1` logic—as well as a few other things.

Anyway, here is an array of test values including extra values for a `Blue` color in addition to the `Red`; cleaned up code to follow:

```
// Test data array.
$product_combinations = array();

$product_combinations[0][product_colour_sizes_id] = 37105;
$product_combinations[0][product_colour_sizes_product_id] = 810;
$product_combinations[0][product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] = 61;
$product_combinations[0][product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] = 904;
$product_combinations[0][quantity] = 999;
$product_combinations[0][product_colour_sizes_name_sizes] = '16-165';
$product_combinations[0][product_colour_sizes_name_colours] = 'Red';

$product_combinations[1][product_colour_sizes_id] = 37104;
$product_combinations[1][product_colour_sizes_product_id] = 810;
$product_combinations[1][product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] = 61;
$product_combinations[1][product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] = 905;
$product_combinations[1][quantity] = 999;
$product_combinations[1][product_colour_sizes_name_sizes] = '17-175';
$product_combinations[1][product_colour_sizes_name_colours] = 'Red';

$product_combinations[2][product_colour_sizes_id] = 37103;
$product_combinations[2][product_colour_sizes_product_id] = 810;
$product_combinations[2][product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] = 61;
$product_combinations[2][product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] = 906;
$product_combinations[2][quantity] = 999;
$product_combinations[2][product_colour_sizes_name_sizes] = '185-19';
$product_combinations[2][product_colour_sizes_name_colours] = 'Red';

$product_combinations[3][product_colour_sizes_id] = 37102;
$product_combinations[3][product_colour_sizes_product_id] = 810;
$product_combinations[3][product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] = 61;
$product_combinations[3][product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] = 907;
$product_combinations[3][quantity] = 999;
$product_combinations[3][product_colour_sizes_name_sizes] = '19.5';
$product_combinations[3][product_colour_sizes_name_colours] = 'Red';

$product_combinations[4][product_colour_sizes_id] = 37102;
$product_combinations[4][product_colour_sizes_product_id] = 810;
$product_combinations[4][product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] = 61;
$product_combinations[4][product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] = 907;
$product_combinations[4][quantity] = 999;
$product_combinations[4][product_colour_sizes_name_sizes] = '19.5';
$product_combinations[4][product_colour_sizes_name_colours] = 'Blue';

$product_combinations[5][product_colour_sizes_id] = 37103;
$product_combinations[5][product_colour_sizes_product_id] = 810;
$product_combinations[5][product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] = 61;
$product_combinations[5][product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] = 906;
$product_combinations[5][quantity] = 999;
$product_combinations[5][product_colour_sizes_name_sizes] = '185-19';
$product_combinations[5][product_colour_sizes_name_colours] = 'Blue';
```

And here is the reworked code logic based on the original poster’s code & desired output:

```
// Init the colours array.
$colours = array();

// Init the sizes array.
$sizes = array();

// Init the increment array.
$increment = array();

// Main logic.
foreach ($product_combinations as $key => $product_combination){

  // Set the color & id.
  $color = $product_combinations[$key]['product_colour_sizes_name_colours'];
  $id = $product_combinations[$key]['product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id'];

  // Set the sizes array data.
  $sizes[$color][$id] = $product_combinations[$key]['product_colour_sizes_name_sizes'];
  $sizes[$color]['quantity'] = $product_combinations[$key]['quantity'];
  $sizes[$color]['product_colour_sizes_id'] = $product_combination['product_colour_sizes_id'];
  $sizes[$color]['product_colour_sizes_product_id'] = $product_combination['product_colour_sizes_product_id'];
  $sizes[$color]['product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id'] = $product_combination['product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id'];
  $sizes[$color]['product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id' . $increment[$color]] = $product_combination['product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id'];
  $increment[$color]++;

  // Now place the colours array in the sizes array.
  $colours[$color] = $sizes[$color];

} // foreach
```

And the output of that would be:

```
Array
(
    [Red] => Array
        (
            [904] => 16-165
            [quantity] => 999
            [product_colour_sizes_id] => 37102
            [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 810
            [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 61
            [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 904
            [905] => 17-175
            [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id1] => 905
            [906] => 185-19
            [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id2] => 906
            [907] => 19.5
            [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id3] => 907
        )

    [Blue] => Array
        (
            [907] => 19.5
            [quantity] => 999
            [product_colour_sizes_id] => 37103
            [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 810
            [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 61
            [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 907
            [906] => 185-19
            [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id1] => 906
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It's someone else's code which i do plan on re-factoring.  Anyway, this returns me an empty array of `colours[]`. Seems they're not getting pushed. Will look more into it.

Comment: Thanks again @JakeGould i appreciate the help. The issue I'm having with your example above is that the last row i am try to get is still being omitted.  `[3] => Array
    (
        [product_colour_sizes_id] => 37102
        [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 810
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 61
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 907
        [quantity] => 999
        [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes] => 19.5  
        [product_colour_sizes_name_colours] => Red
    )`